Sending transaction from web3 takes super long
I'm sending basic transactions from 1 account to another to see how long it takes. Here is the current code I have:
async function main() {
  const connection = new Connection("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/");
  const tipAddress = new PublicKey(
    "DfXygSm4jCyNCybVYYK6DwvWqjKee8pbDmJGcLWNDXjh"
  );
  const tipAmount = 1000000;

  (async () => {
    const transaction = new Transaction()
      .add(addPriorityFee)
      .add(
        SystemProgram.transfer({
          fromPubkey: base_wallet.publicKey,
          toPubkey: to_wallet.publicKey,
          lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL / 100,
        })
      )
      .add(
        SystemProgram.transfer({
          fromPubkey: base_wallet.publicKey,
          toPubkey: tipAddress,
          lamports: tipAmount,
        })
      );

    // Sign transaction, broadcast, and confirm
    console.log("Sending SOL to test wallet");
    const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [
      base_wallet.payer,
    ]);
    console.log("SIGNATURE", signature);
  })();
}

main();

Problem is it takes super long for the transaction to land. Here is my testing so far:
Sol rpc. No fees set. 
[[11:44:13.080]] [LOG]   Sending SOL to test wallet
[[11:45:54.469]] [LOG]   SIGNATURE 5Ni9uk2nnTr9RY9Yp7bK3JbpbkLb69sKWkuQmow1SPWzs9WFyhMCkstVFnedA6DD7TXrEsxRoR8NjsQ9wGUPmi2b
Actually dropped 11:44:30. 17 sec delay.

Sol rpc. PriorityFee 20000 microLamports:
[[11:54:11.464]] [LOG]   Sending SOL to test wallet
[[11:54:55.200]] [LOG]   SIGNATURE qTJehYfkr7yYfjFrt3jUrdPCSXk89FvCM7PeQn4j8cb6RVEsTTPHf5xjSU5rcL4Zmk7nkXNNLAgKJ9pmkxECgym
Actually dropped 11:54:30. 19 sec delay.

Quicknode rpc. PriorityFee 20000 microLamports:
[[11:57:12.521]] [LOG]   Sending SOL to test wallet
[[11:58:35.134]] [LOG]   SIGNATURE 3UWQT73RpMnZrgqtRcwWvopfmZnFZd3NabsURWMoAQvSyQqrdt6hAChNwwtzh6P8oJXss1Xp5i92sHnVa763k9E3
Actually dropped 11:58:00. 48 sec delay.

Quicknode rpc, PriorityFee 600000 microLamports:
Failed, block height exceeded.

Sol rpc, PriorityFee 600000 microLamports:
[[12:11:32.650]] [LOG]   Sending SOL to test wallet
[[12:12:23.924]] [LOG]   SIGNATURE 5BZMRfMvKULyuPTnTszdiTvBG1SYkxC7zmtno2YGasJm8cRVpManbd5ZVqKNTKvxWLp8ywkEfdJTKczphdKz8kPM
Actually dropped 12:12:05. 33 sec delay

Sol rpc, PriorityFee 600000 microLamports, Jito tip of 500000:
block height exceeded.

Retry sol rpc, PriorityFee 600000 microLamports, Jito tip of 500000:
block height exceeded.

Retry sol rpc, PriorityFee 600000 microLamports, Jito tip of 1000000:
block height exceeded.

By actually dropped I mean the time I see on solscan.
Unsure if I am doing the Jito tip correctly, all 3 transactions I've tried since adding that code has failed.
Any suggestions on how I can improve this/where I'm going wrong? I understand the network can be congested but if I pay enough fees shouldn't my transaction go thru/go thru faster?
Thanks for your help
Edit:
I don't understand why I can't even send money to jito tip addresses. I add the following:
  const tipAddress = new PublicKey(
    "96gYZGLnJYVFmbjzopPSU6QiEV5fGqZNyN9nmNhvrZU5"
  );

And then just try to send money to the tipAddress, like I've been sending money to my own address. No other transfers (I remove my own original transfer). But despite this, the transaction never goes thru (get a txId, but nothing on explorer). But if I switch the address to my to_wallet, it goes through.
